# In SSRS, parameter field is coming blank rather than a dropdown

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS, I am creating a cascading parameterized report, where i have three fields. 
City
AgencyID 
AgencyName

AgencyID is dependent on City and AgencyName is dependent on AgencyID .

When i am selecting city, corresponding AgencyID of that city is appearing but when i select Any of the AgencyID, AgencyName is appearing blank

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please clarifyyour question. Sample test query/data would be very helpful as well.

Comment: AgencyName field  is appearing blank rather than a dropdown.This field should have dropdown.

Below is the query using in dataset to map with AgencyName  parameter 

select distinct [dbo].[Agency].[AgencyName] from [dbo].[Agency]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AgencyCandidateAddress] On  [dbo].[AgencyCandidateAddress].[AgencyCandidateAddressId] = [dbo].[Agency].[AgencyId]
where  [dbo].[Agency].[AgencyId] = @AgencyId
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please run your query manually by providing the agency_id value and see if there are any results. Reason because if the query does not yield any results then we do not see a drop down list in the report.
2. Make sure the parameter name under parameters and the parameter name being passed to the query are matching. SSRS matches that when using a cascading drop down.

Hope this helps!

www.roughbook.co.in